# How to fix submit button not submitting (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making an abuse/bullying awareness program (like safe-to-tell) where you select the problem and location, and then put in a name and press submit. However, the code I wrote for the submit function doesn't register any of the inputs.

I switched to a submit button because the previous revision was hard to use for new users.

```py
from tkinter import *

global f
global l
f.set("")
l.set("")

def victim():
    b = "Victim"

def perp():
    b = "Perpetrator"

def victimhome():
            print("")
            print("Unsafe Situation Reported")
            print("Report of Victim")
            print("Location: Home")
            print("Name:", f.get(), l.get())
            print("")

        def victimschool():
            print("")
            print("Unsafe Situation Reported")
            print("Report of Victim")
            print("Location: School")
            print("Name:", f.get(), l.get())
            print("")

        def victimother():
            print("")
            print("Unsafe Situation Reported")
            print("Report of Victim")
            print("Location: Other")
            print("Name:", f.get(), l.get())
            print("")

        def perphome():
            print("")
            print("Unsafe Situation Reported")
            print("Report of Perpetrator")
            print("Location: Home")
            print("Name:", f.get(), l.get())
            print("")

        def perpschool():
            print("")
            print("Unsafe Situation Reported")
            print("Report of Perpetrator")
            print("Location: School")
            print("Name:", f.get(), l.get())
            print("")

        def perpother():
            print("")
            print("Unsafe Situation Reported")
            print("Report of Perpetrator")
            print("Location: Other")
            print("Name:", f.get(), l.get())
            print("")

def submit():
            if b == "Victim":
                x = 1
            elif b == "Perpetrator":
                x = 2
            else:
                x = 3

            if x == 1:
                if bb == 1:
                    victimhome()
                elif bb == 2:
                    victimschool()
                elif bb == 3:
                    victimother()
                else:
                    print("")
            elif x == 2:
                if bb == 1:
                    perphome()
                elif bb == 2:
                    perpschool()
                elif bb == 3:
                    perpother()
                else:
                    print("")
            elif x == 3:
                print("")
            else:
                print("")


victimbuttons1 = Radiobutton(self, text='Home', width = 30, variable=bb, value = 1, indicatoron = 0)

victimbuttons2 = Radiobutton(self, text='School', width = 30, variable=bb, value = 2, indicatoron = 0)

victimbuttons3 = Radiobutton(self, text='Other', width = 30, variable=bb, value = 3, indicatoron = 0)

victimentry1 = Entry(self, textvariable = f)
victimentry2 = Entry(self, textvariable = l)

victimsubmit = Button(self, text = 'Submit', command = submit)



perpbuttons1 = Radiobutton(self, text='Home', width = 30, variable=bb, value = 1, indicatoron = 0)

perpbuttons2 = Radiobutton(self, text='School', width = 30, variable=bb, value = 2, indicatoron = 0)

perpbuttons3 = Radiobutton(self, text='Other', width = 30, variable=bb, value = 3, indicatoron = 0)

perpentry1 = Entry(self, textvariable = f)
perpentry2 = Entry(self, textvariable = l)

perpsubmit = Button(self, text = 'Submit', command = submit)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x500')
f = StringVar()
l = StringVar()
victimbuttons1.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
victimbuttons2.grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
victimbuttons3.grid(row = 6, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
victimentry1.grid(row = 9, column =1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
victimentry2.grid(row = 10, column =1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
victimsubmit.grid(row = 11, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 10)
perpbuttons1.grid(row = 4, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
perpbuttons2.grid(row = 5, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
perpbuttons3.grid(row = 6, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
perpentry1.grid(row = 9, column = 2, padx = 5,  pady = 5)
perpentry2.grid(row = 9, column = 2, padx = 5,  pady = 5)
perpsubmit.grid(row = 11, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 10)
root.title('Bullying and Abuse Hotline')
root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to get the program to print some info into the terminal when the button is pressed, but at the moment it just creates a newline.

Comment: `global` needs to be removed from the top. It is doing nothing there. You need to define global inside of your functions that are using the global variable. Also the `set()`'s at the top need to be moved to below where you define the `f` and `l` `StringVar()`'s.

Comment: Full code [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1X4FVmkh-1HqqvCAMrlUf8KZcCDUSMiclSxYU2KKVY5k/edit?usp=sharing), sorry

Answer (score 0):

You never call the functions victim() or perp() that would set variable b, so the x value is always 3 and you do a print.

Also put `global b` inside the two functions victim and perp, or b will be local.

some recommendations use constants for the strings "Victim" and "Perpetrator":

```
VICTIM = "Victim"
PERPETRATOR = "Perpetrator"
```

Also use better naming for variables than just x or b (maybe person_kind). 
You can also drop the if b == ... then set x, and just use the person_kind (or whatever nice name you select)

```
if person_kind == VICTIM:
    ... do something for Victim
elif person_kind == PERPETRATOR:
    ... do something for Perpetrator
```

and so on

Also try to avoid global variables if possible.
Good luck

Comment: Sorry for not including the lines that call victim and perp, I was rushed to get out of class. I do have functions that show and hide some buttons, and the program still doesn't work.

Comment: ok, also put global b inside those functions, I added that to the response

Comment: I made b global, but the output is just a newline.